# compute the integral $ \int _0 ^ \pi \frac {\sin((n+1/2)t) }{t} dt $

Tags: integration

I want to compute an integral, but I don't know how. The exercice is about the proof of this equality : $  \int _0 ^ \pi \frac {\sin(t) }{t} dt = \frac{\pi}{2} $. One step require to show this equality :

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int _0 ^ \pi \frac {\sin((n+1/2)t) }{t} dt = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Do you have any idea? I tried to use an integration by part, ive found :

$$ -[ \frac{cos((n+1/2)t)}{(n+1/2)t} ]^\pi_0  - \int _0 ^ \pi \frac {\cos((n+1/2)t) }{(n+1/2) t^2} dt $$

but this one is not defined... wheras the first expression is defined (because in 0 $\ sin(t) / t $ is defined.
I don't know what to do.

Thank you :)

Comment: The mentioned equality is not an equality, indeed. On the other hand, $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin((n+1/2)t)}{t}\,dt = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$ We also have $$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt = \text{Si}(\pi) > \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: oh yes sorry, but you understood the point, how to prove it?

Comment: @MarineGalantin what about changing variables ?

Comment: @MarineGalantin but you should be accurate with that.

Comment: I'm maybe not... I'm open to any suggestion :)

Comment: By Fubini's theorem
$$\int_{0}^{M}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{M}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x)e^{-\lambda x}\,d\lambda\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{d\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(M)+\lambda\sin(M)}{(1+\lambda^2)e^{\lambda M}}d\lambda $$
and of course $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{d\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and

$$ \left|\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(M)+\lambda\sin(M)}{(1+\lambda^2)e^{\lambda M}}d\lambda\right| \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{d\lambda}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2} e^{\lambda M}}\leq \frac{1}{M}. $$

Comment: It follows that $\lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{M}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and for any $A>0$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(Ax)}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi A}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx $$
by a straightforward substitution.

Comment: I will see Fubini's theorem only in a few weeks... any other idea? but thank you I ll take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by considering the rather unusual function
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{2 \sin (t/2)}, \quad 0 < t \leqslant \pi.$$
At $t = 0$ the value for the function is understood as its limiting value as $t \to 0^+$ so in this case we may write $f(0) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} f(t) = 0$. Thus $f$ will be continuous for all $t \in [0,\pi]$ and its derivative can be shown to also be continuous for all $t$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Now consider the integral
$$\int_0^\pi \sin \left (\left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) f(t) \, dt.$$

Integrating by parts we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi \sin \left (\left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) f(t) \, dt &= \left [\frac{-1}{n + \frac{1}{2}} \cos \left ( \left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) \cdot f(t) \right ]_0^\pi\\
& \qquad + \frac{1}{n + \frac{1}{2}} \int_0^\pi \cos \left ( \left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) \cdot f'(t) \, dt.
\end{align*}
As $f(0) = 0$ and $\cos (n + \frac{1}{2}) \pi = 0$, the above integral reduces to
$$\int_0^\pi \sin \left (\left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) f(t) \, dt = \frac{1}{n + \frac{1}{2}} \int_0^\pi \cos \left ( \left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) \cdot f'(t) \, dt. \tag1$$

Now as $f'(t)$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$, $|f'(t)|$ will be bounded by some constant $M > 0$. Thus $|f'(t)| \leqslant M$ and we have 
\begin{align*}
\left |\int_0^\pi \cos \left (\left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) f'(t) \, dt \right | &\leqslant \int_0^\pi \left |\cos \left (\left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) \right | \cdot |f'(t)| \, dt\\
&\leqslant \int_0^\pi |f'(t)| \, dt, \quad \text{since} \,\, |\cos (n + \frac{1}{2})t| \leqslant 1\\
&\leqslant M \int_0^\pi dt, \quad \text{since} \,\, |f'(t)| \leqslant M\\
&= M \pi,
\end{align*}
or
$$\left |\frac{1}{n + \frac{1}{2}} \int_0^\pi \cos \left (\left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) f'(t) \, dt \right | \leqslant \frac{M \pi}{n + \frac{1}{2}},\tag2$$
after dividing both side by the positive term $n + \frac{1}{2}$.

In the limit as $n \to \infty$ from (2) we see that
$$\left |\frac{1}{n + \frac{1}{2}} \int_0^\pi \cos \left (\left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) f'(t) \, dt \right | \to 0,$$
and so from (1) conclude that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\pi \sin \left (\left (n + \frac{1}{2} \right ) t \right ) f(t) \, dt = 0,$$
or
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left [\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (n + \frac{1}{2}) t}{t} \, dt - \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (n + \frac{1}{2}) t}{2 \sin (t/2)} \, dt \right ] = 0.\tag3$$

Now the second integral appearing in (3) can be found. From the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel), namely
$$\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k = 1}^n \cos (kx) = \frac{\sin (n + \frac{1}{2}) x}{2 \sin (\frac{x}{2})},$$ we see that
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (n + \frac{1}{2}) t}{2 \sin (\frac{t}{2})} \, dt = \int_0^\pi \left [\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k = 1}^n \cos (kt) \right ] \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
So (3) becomes
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left [\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (n + \frac{1}{2}) t}{t} \, dt - \frac{\pi}{2} \right ] = 0,$$
or
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (n + \frac{1}{2}) t}{t} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2},$$
as required to show.